# Latin American Moto G2 locked in Europe?

Tags: sim-unlocking, motorola-moto-g2

I bought an unlocked Moto G2 (2014) in Chile last year, model XT1063. It was new but on display in a store, no connection to any service providers, no contract, no sim lock.
I use CyanogenMod 13, it runs fine.
However, now I am trying to use it in Europe and it won't work with my German SIM card. It says "SIM card is Perso locked" and requires my "SIM network unlock pin".

My Chilean service provider confirmed that the phone is completely unlocked (so SIM unlocking via web services does not apply).
According to willmyphonework.net, the phone should work in Europe.

Any ideas what I could try to make it work? 
Thanks!

[image: SIM card is Perso locked] [image: SIM network unlock PIN]
<sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

The network unlock PIN is NOT the normal PIN protection of the SIM card; I use the SIM card in another phone, it works perfectly well.

edit: desperately, I wipe the phone and installed current LineageOS 14.1, but to no avail. The "Perso locked" message now simply reads "SIM card is locked".

Comment: Have you tried a different SIM (in a shop, they should be able to give you some to try)? May be a fault with the SIM card itself. Never heard a card being "Perso" locked (what shall that be? Can you attach a screenshot of that message?)

Comment: Try `1234` or `0000` which are usually default SIM unlock keys

Comment: @Izzy: edited my post. The SIM works fine in another phone. Tried a friend's SIM in my phone, didn't work either.

Comment: @beeshyams: it's not asking for the "normal" SIM unlock code.

Comment: How did you make sure that it was unlocked when purchased? I'm thinking that the dealer fooled you in some way... The fact that this is a demo device only makes it more likely.

Comment: @AndyYan: In Chile, I have been able to use different SIM cards from different providers. Also my current provider confirmed (they say), using my IMEI, that the phone is unlocked. Seems to be the case in Chile, but not abroad.